# Returning inner array elements from multiple document in sorted form

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

hyy there, my collection goes like this and I am trying to get all comments list of particular blog_id in sorted order of date.

```
    [
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("565f0f5d77f0c7bd11bbadd8"),
    "blog_id" : ObjectId("56587befdb7224110f007233"),
    "comments" : [
        {
            "user_id" : ObjectId("562fa014888806820e21e0df"),
            "user_full_name" : "Niroj Paudel",
            "comment" : "pradip is bhole baba",
            "_id" : ObjectId("565f0f5d77f0c7bd11bbadd9"),
            "dt" : ISODate("2015-12-02T15:33:49.578Z")
        },
        {
            "user_id" : ObjectId("562fa014888806820e21e0df"),
            "user_full_name" : "Niroj Paudel",
            "comment" : "honkog pokhara... he he ha ha",
            "_id" : ObjectId("565f1034fd07cbfc1129db0b"),
            "dt" : ISODate("2015-12-02T15:37:24.581Z")
        }
    ],
    "record_count" : 2,
    "__v" : 0
}


{
    "_id" : ObjectId("565efa37635f09900d21a339"),
    "blog_id" : ObjectId("56587befdb7224110f007233"),
    "comments" : [
        {
            "user_id" : ObjectId("562fa014888806820e21e0df"),
            "user_full_name" : "Niroj Paudel",
            "comment" : "wat a nice car wow",
            "_id" : ObjectId("565efa37635f09900d21a33a"),
            "dt" : ISODate("2015-12-02T14:03:35.289Z")
        },
        {
            "user_id" : ObjectId("562fa014888806820e21e0df"),
            "user_full_name" : "Niroj Paudel",
            "comment" : "love is life budikhola ma dives",
            "_id" : ObjectId("565efa76635f09900d21a33b"),
            "dt" : ISODate("2015-12-02T14:04:38.661Z")
        },
        {
            "user_id" : ObjectId("562fa014888806820e21e0df"),
            "user_full_name" : "Niroj Paudel",
            "comment" : "bholi ajaya ko bihe",
            "_id" : ObjectId("565efaa0635f09900d21a33c"),
            "dt" : ISODate("2015-12-02T14:05:20.847Z")
        },
        {
            "user_id" : ObjectId("562fa014888806820e21e0df"),
            "user_full_name" : "Niroj Paudel",
            "comment" : "manish is nice",
            "_id" : ObjectId("565efb17635f09900d21a33d"),
            "dt" : ISODate("2015-12-02T14:07:19.704Z")
        },
        {
            "user_id" : ObjectId("562fa014888806820e21e0df"),
            "user_full_name" : "Niroj Paudel",
            "comment" : "niroj is cool",
            "_id" : ObjectId("565efd53c22dddc80e8f461c"),
            "dt" : ISODate("2015-12-02T14:16:51.730Z")
        },
        {
            "user_id" : ObjectId("562fa014888806820e21e0df"),
            "user_full_name" : "Niroj Paudel",
            "comment" : "ramesh is cool",
            "_id" : ObjectId("565f0d376d82e24c11f6c0d1"),
            "dt" : ISODate("2015-12-02T15:24:39.010Z")
        }
    ],
    "record_count" : 6,
    "__v" : 0
}
]
```

I want to list all comments of particular blog_id in descending order of date like below

```
    

[

        {
            "user_id" : ObjectId("562fa014888806820e21e0df"),
            "user_full_name" : "Niroj Paudel",
            "comment" : "wat a nice car wow",
            "_id" : ObjectId("565efa37635f09900d21a33a"),
            "dt" : ISODate("2015-12-02T14:03:35.289Z")
        },
        {
            "user_id" : ObjectId("562fa014888806820e21e0df"),
            "user_full_name" : "Niroj Paudel",
            "comment" : "love is life budikhola ma dives",
            "_id" : ObjectId("565efa76635f09900d21a33b"),
            "dt" : ISODate("2015-12-02T14:04:38.661Z")
        },
        {
            "user_id" : ObjectId("562fa014888806820e21e0df"),
            "user_full_name" : "Niroj Paudel",
            "comment" : "bholi ajaya ko bihe",
            "_id" : ObjectId("565efaa0635f09900d21a33c"),
            "dt" : ISODate("2015-12-02T14:05:20.847Z")
        },
        {
            "user_id" : ObjectId("562fa014888806820e21e0df"),
            "user_full_name" : "Niroj Paudel",
            "comment" : "manish is nice",
            "_id" : ObjectId("565efb17635f09900d21a33d"),
            "dt" : ISODate("2015-12-02T14:07:19.704Z")
        },
        {
            "user_id" : ObjectId("562fa014888806820e21e0df"),
            "user_full_name" : "Niroj Paudel",
            "comment" : "niroj is cool",
            "_id" : ObjectId("565efd53c22dddc80e8f461c"),
            "dt" : ISODate("2015-12-02T14:16:51.730Z")
        },
        {
            "user_id" : ObjectId("562fa014888806820e21e0df"),
            "user_full_name" : "Niroj Paudel",
            "comment" : "ramesh is cool",
            "_id" : ObjectId("565f0d376d82e24c11f6c0d1"),
            "dt" : ISODate("2015-12-02T15:24:39.010Z")
        }
                {
            "user_id" : ObjectId("562fa014888806820e21e0df"),
            "user_full_name" : "Niroj Paudel",
            "comment" : "pradip is bhole baba",
            "_id" : ObjectId("565f0f5d77f0c7bd11bbadd9"),
            "dt" : ISODate("2015-12-02T15:33:49.578Z")
        },
        {
            "user_id" : ObjectId("562fa014888806820e21e0df"),
            "user_full_name" : "Niroj Paudel",
            "comment" : "honkog pokhara... he he ha ha",
            "_id" : ObjectId("565f1034fd07cbfc1129db0b"),
            "dt" : ISODate("2015-12-02T15:37:24.581Z")
        }
]
```

how Can I do this in mongooes or mongodb

I had tried this

```
BlogComments.aggregate([

            {$match:{blog_id:blogId}},
            {
                $group:{
                    _id:statusId,comment_count:{$sum:"$record_count"},comments:{$push:"$comments"}
                 }
            },
            { "$unwind": "$comments" },
            { "$unwind": "$comments" },


            { "$group": {
                "_id": statusId,
                "comment_count": { "$first": "$comment_count" },
                "comments": { "$addToSet": "$comments" }
            }},
            { $sort: {'comments._id': 1}}


        ]);
```

This query gives comment and all associated comments from the multiple document but comments are in random order. $sort is not properly working for me

Thank you in advance.

Comment: John, have you tried anything?

Comment: yes but the comment list is random not sorted.... I had used aggregation framework with $match $group $sort and $unwind

Comment: Please update your question and post the actual code you tried and what the output error was

Comment: I had updated by question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jorin,

Try this:

```
db.comments.aggregate(
[
  {$match: {blog_id: ObjectId("56587befdb7224110f007233")}}, //match blogid
  {"$unwind": "$comments"}, //unwind the comments array
  {$sort: {"comments.dt": 1}}, //sort the comment documents by date
  {
    "$group": {
        "_id": '$blog_id', //group comment documents by blog_id
        "comments": {
            "$push": "$comments" //push comments of same blog_id into an array
        }
    }
}])
```

Based upon your sample data the output will be:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("56587befdb7224110f007233"),
    "comments" : [
        {
            "user_id" : ObjectId("562fa014888806820e21e0df"),
            "user_full_name" : "Niroj Paudel",
            "comment" : "wat a nice car wow",
            "_id" : ObjectId("565efa37635f09900d21a33a"),
            "dt" : ISODate("2015-12-02T14:03:35.289Z")
        },
        {
            "user_id" : ObjectId("562fa014888806820e21e0df"),
            "user_full_name" : "Niroj Paudel",
            "comment" : "love is life budikhola ma dives",
            "_id" : ObjectId("565efa76635f09900d21a33b"),
            "dt" : ISODate("2015-12-02T14:04:38.661Z")
        },
        {
            "user_id" : ObjectId("562fa014888806820e21e0df"),
            "user_full_name" : "Niroj Paudel",
            "comment" : "bholi ajaya ko bihe",
            "_id" : ObjectId("565efaa0635f09900d21a33c"),
            "dt" : ISODate("2015-12-02T14:05:20.847Z")
        },
        {
            "user_id" : ObjectId("562fa014888806820e21e0df"),
            "user_full_name" : "Niroj Paudel",
            "comment" : "manish is nice",
            "_id" : ObjectId("565efb17635f09900d21a33d"),
            "dt" : ISODate("2015-12-02T14:07:19.704Z")
        },
        {
            "user_id" : ObjectId("562fa014888806820e21e0df"),
            "user_full_name" : "Niroj Paudel",
            "comment" : "niroj is cool",
            "_id" : ObjectId("565efd53c22dddc80e8f461c"),
            "dt" : ISODate("2015-12-02T14:16:51.730Z")
        },
        {
            "user_id" : ObjectId("562fa014888806820e21e0df"),
            "user_full_name" : "Niroj Paudel",
            "comment" : "ramesh is cool",
            "_id" : ObjectId("565f0d376d82e24c11f6c0d1"),
            "dt" : ISODate("2015-12-02T15:24:39.010Z")
        },
        {
            "user_id" : ObjectId("562fa014888806820e21e0df"),
            "user_full_name" : "Niroj Paudel",
            "comment" : "pradip is bhole baba",
            "_id" : ObjectId("565f0f5d77f0c7bd11bbadd9"),
            "dt" : ISODate("2015-12-02T15:33:49.578Z")
        },
        {
            "user_id" : ObjectId("562fa014888806820e21e0df"),
            "user_full_name" : "Niroj Paudel",
            "comment" : "honkog pokhara... he he ha ha",
            "_id" : ObjectId("565f1034fd07cbfc1129db0b"),
            "dt" : ISODate("2015-12-02T15:37:24.581Z")
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: this will give result like this [
  {
    "_id": "56587befdb7224110f007233"
  }
]

Comment: @Jorin Sorry updated my answer. Missed a step. Push all the comments into a comment array holder. The updated answer should give you the desired output

Comment: Thank you, Its working . one question is it possible to limit comments array to contain only last 5 comments.

Comment: after the sort stage in the pipeline before the grouping?

Comment: thank you $limit , $skip all working....  Thanks once again.  Inspired i am trying to implement the page bucket can you suggest me some books or article which could help me

Comment: :) Glad I could help!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96822/discussion-between-jorin-and-inspired).

Answer (score 0):

to do this, you can use method `findById` then sort your comments with method `sort` of mongoose.

With a example :

```
Blog.find({blog_id : YOUR_BLOG_ID}, 'comments')
.sort('dt')
.exec(function(err, docs){
 console.log(docs); // do whatever you want with your docs
});
```

Something like that should do the job.

Comment: this will do sorting only for single document. I want comments from multiple document of particular blog_id to be aggregated and sorted