# MongoDB $orderby not working with monk

Tags: node.js, mongodb, sorting, sql-order-by, monk

After following the documentation to the letter, I can not get $orderby to work in NodeJS.

Here is my route in NodeJS:

```
  // gets all the reviews about an instructor
  app.get('/findInstructorReviews/:instructorID', function(req, res) {

    var commentCollection = req.db.get('comments');

    commentCollection.findOne(
      { _id: ObjectID(req.params.instructorID) },
      {
        $orderby: { 'comments.startDateTime' : -1 } 
      },
    function(err, instructorReviews){debug(err);

      if(err) return res.send({ status: 500, data: 'There was an error retreiving the instructor\'s reviews. Please try again later.' });
      if(!instructorReviews) return res.send({ status: 404, data: 'This instructor does not have any review yet.' });

      return res.send({ status: 200, data: instructorReviews.comments });
    });
  });
```

Here is the comments collection in my DB:

```
> db.comments.find().pretty()
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("58d027f003232ca34e43d734"),
        "comments" : [
                {
                        "eventID" : ObjectId("58d2cd4e2f77b34b73dd8a04"),
                        "eventName" : "Yoga in the Park",
                        "startDateTime" : ISODate("2017-03-22T19:20:00Z"),
                        "comments" : [
                                "I really enjoyed his Yoga class.",
                                "He really helped me stretch out!",
                                "He taught me doggy style ;)"
                        ]
                },
                {
                        "eventID" : ObjectId("58d2cd752f77b34b73dd8a05"),
                        "eventName" : "Spanish Lessons",
                        "startDateTime" : ISODate("2017-03-22T19:20:00Z"),
                        "comments" : [
                                "Learned a lot!",
                                "La biblioteca es manana!"
                        ]
                },
                {
                        "eventID" : ObjectId("58d4130d5e18cdc928d0b82a"),
                        "eventName" : "Basketball Practice",
                        "startDateTime" : ISODate("2017-03-23T18:30:00Z"),
                        "comments" : [
                                "great guy! helped me improve my shooting game!",
                                "really knowledgeable about basketball!",
                                "excellent coach"
                        ]
                }
        ]
}
```

The one document in the comments collection is being returned to NodeJS, but not sorted by startDateTime like I want it to. It is being returned in the order it's already in - which would be Yoga, Spanish, Basketball. I've also tried sorting by 1 instead of -1, but that did not change the results.

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Edit: I am using monk v1.0.1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Returning inner array elements from multiple document in sorted form](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34048084/returning-inner-array-elements-from-multiple-document-in-sorted-form)

Comment: Thank you. My question is a duplicate.

Comment: My question is a duplicate of [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34048084/returning-inner-array-elements-from-multiple-document-in-sorted-form](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34048084/returning-inner-array-elements-from-multiple-document-in-sorted-form)